# How to avoid fragment reload after onBackPressed Android

Tags: android, fragment

I used fragment to show Vehicle list in recycler view.
Whenever user clicks on Vehicle then it shows its details in another fragment,
but when i comeback on Vehicle list fragment after getting its details using back button pressed then Vehicle list fragment loads like first time.
I used load more in recycler view.
That's why whenever user scrolls much more and if he wanted to see details of the vehicle and then come back on list it reloads like first time and user gets first item back...

## Recycler view scroll listener in Vehicle list Fragment

```
rvVehicleList.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) rvVehicleList.getLayoutManager()) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            if (!vehicleSearchResponseModel.getData().get_links().getNext().equals("")) {
                pageNo++;
                searchMoreVehicle(pageNo);
            }
        }
    });
```

## Recycler view's on Click from adapter for vehicle info Fragment

```
holder.llMainView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("vehicleInfo", vehicleSearchPagerList.get(position));

            VehicleAdInfoFragment vehicleAdInfoFragment = new VehicleAdInfoFragment();
            vehicleAdInfoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frContainer, vehicleAdInfoFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(vehicleAdInfoFragment.getTag());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How you close the detail screen and have you written some function on onResume method ?

Comment: No,I do not write any code in onResume method of vehicle list fragment

Comment: And how you close the detail screen ?

Comment: just using back button press

Comment: please take a look into fragment back stack feature,it will be a solution for your problem

Answer (score 3):

To restrict the recreation of the fragment, what I did:

In `onCreateView` you can store inflated view in a global variable and initialize it only if it is `null`, like in this code:

```
    var root:View?=null
    var apiDataReceived=false
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (root==null)
        root=inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
    return root
}
```

Now if you are parsing some data and fill it into `RecyclerView` or any other `View`

1. Make a global variable like in the above code `apiDataReceived`
2. Set it to true if you successfully parsed data.
3. Before apiCalls place a condition like this:

   if (!apiDataReceived) {
   apiCalls()
   }

So if apiCalls() would be called only if data is not parsed.

Do your HTTP calls and parsing or any other thing in a method which called after `onCreateView` like `onStart`

The above code is in kotlin, If you are facing any issue, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your vehicle list fragment:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    mCurrentIndex = ((LinearLayoutManager) rvVehicleList.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    editor.putInt("current_position", mCurrentIndex);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mCurrentIndex = preferences.getInt("current_position", 0);
    rvVehicleList.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mCurrentIndex);
}
```

Comment: This is not a proper way... If i use this method then i used load more in recyclerview so if user scrolls more then one time and then he see vehicle detail and then come back to list fragment and it loads only first page data and then how to set 3rd page position in recyclerview with only first page data????

Comment: I guess you should save your page number in onPause() too, then load it back in onResume() and show proper page

Comment: Assume i got 3 results per page, user scrolls 3 times and get 9 result then he gets details of 9th item and if i stores the position and come back then first of all needs to execute 3 page data then i can set position 9th to recyclerview even if i already load that data and still not close fragment...

Comment: please take a look into fragment back stack feature,it will be a solution for your problem

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be where you do not need to replace fragment instead use add() method. 
This is the only thing that worked in my case to avoid reloading of previous fragment.

```
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) 
{
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager .findFragmentById(R.id.container)  //get current fragment
        transaction.hide(currentFragment!!)          //hide current fragment
        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment)    //add next fragment
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
```